# Convolution of functions from $L^p$ and $L^q$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$, $g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue's measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$.

I am to show that $f * g = \int f(x-y)g(y) \, dy$ is integrable. How can I check it? Should I just try to compute
$$\int \int |f(x-y)g(y)| \, dy \, dx ?$$

If yes how can I use the fact that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$ and $g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to apply Hölder’s inequality, Fubini’s theorem and the fact that Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations. The latter is simply saying that 
$$
\int f(x-y) dx = \int f(x)dx,
$$
for any $y$.

**Edit** Okay so when trying to provide more details, I realized that this might not even be true. By Hölder and invariance the best we have is
$$
\left|\int f(x-y)g(y)dy\right|\leq \int |f(x-y)g(y)| dx \leq  \|f\|_p\|g\|_q < \infty
$$
This gives that $f*g \in L^\infty(\Bbb{R}^d)$. With a little more work, one could probably show that $f*g \in C_0(\Bbb{R}^d)$, but I am not sure this will be even integrable.

Comment: Can you explain it in a more detailed way, please?

Comment: For some insight of what’s going on, at least for $d=1$, you can check this: https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section4c_convolve.pdf